# How to Get Optimal Models From Benchmark For Prediction on Test Data

Tags: mlr, mlr3

This question is applicable to both mlr and mlr3 but I only included the code for mlr since I have it handy.
As an example, when we have 3 folds outer CV, we get 3 sets of optimal hyperparameters (subset of selected/filtered features). Which hyperparameter set should be used for prediction? Does mlr/mlr3 use the average of value for each parameter or the parameter set that is associated with the best performance measure (lowest error or max c-index). What is the best practice for this? Same question for selected/filtered features?

Additional questions

1. How best to get the optimized models from benchmark and use them for prediction on the test set given I set (keep.extract = TRUE & models = TRUE) in the benchmark.
2. How get filtered feature of Cox2 model (getBMRFilteredFeatures returns NULL results)
3. How to get  the importance features from the final models from benchmark? do I get them after I predict on the test set?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)
library(PKPDmisc)
library(mlr)
library(parallelMap)
library(survival)


# Data and Data Splitting  
data = as_tibble(lung) %>% 
       na.omit()      %>% 
       mutate(status = if_else(status==1, 0, 1))

set.seed(123)
split <- data  %>% initial_split(prop = 0.8, strata = status)    
train <- split %>% training()
test  <- split %>% testing()


# Task
task = makeSurvTask(id = "Survival", data = train, target = c("time", "status")) 

 
# Resample 
# For model assessment before external validation on test data
set.seed(123)
outer_cv  = makeResampleDesc("CV", iter=3, stratify.cols = c("status")) %>% 
 makeResampleInstance(task) 

# For feature selection and parameter tuning
set.seed(123)
inner_cv  = makeResampleDesc("CV", iter=3, stratify.cols = c("status"))


# Learners
cox1      = makeLearner(id = "COX1", "surv.coxph") %>%
           makeFeatSelWrapper(resampling = inner_cv, show.info = TRUE,
                              control = makeFeatSelControlSequential(method = "sffs"))
 
cox2      = makeLearner(id = "COX2", "surv.coxph") %>%
           makeFilterWrapper(fw.method = "univariate.model.score") %>% 
           makeTuneWrapper(resampling  = inner_cv, show.info = TRUE, 
                           par.set     = makeParamSet(makeIntegerParam("fw.abs", lower = 2, upper = 10)), 
                           control     = makeTuneControlGrid(resolution = 5L)) 
 
cox_lasso = makeLearner(id = "COX LASSO", "surv.glmnet") %>% 
           makeTuneWrapper(resampling = inner_cv, show.info = TRUE, 
                           par.set    =  makeParamSet(makeNumericParam("lambda",lower = -3, upper = 0.5,
                                                                       trafo = function(x) 10^x)),
                           control    = makeTuneControlGrid(resolution = 5L))
 
cox_net   = makeLearner(id = "COX NET",  "surv.glmnet") %>% 
           makeTuneWrapper(resampling = inner_cv, show.info = TRUE, 
                           par.set    =  makeParamSet(makeNumericParam("alpha", lower = 0,  upper = 1,
                                                                       trafo = function(x) round(x,2)),
                                                      makeNumericParam("lambda",lower = -3, upper = 0.5,
                                                                       trafo = function(x) 10^x)),
                           control    = makeTuneControlGrid(resolution = 5L))
 
rsf       = makeLearner(id = "RSF", "surv.randomForestSRC") %>% 
           makeTuneWrapper(resampling = inner_cv, show.info = T,
                           par.set    = makeParamSet(makeDiscreteParam("ntree", values = c(500,1000,2000)),
                                                     makeIntegerParam("mtry",     lower = 2,  upper = 5),
                                                     makeIntegerParam("nodesize", lower = 2,  upper = 5),
                                                     makeIntegerParam("nsplit",   lower = 2,  upper = 5)),
                           control    = makeTuneControlGrid(resolution = 5L))


# Benchmark 
parallelStartSocket(4)
set.seed(123, "L'Ecuyer") # for reproducible results with parallel computing 
start_time <- Sys.time() 

bmr       = benchmark(learners    = list(cox1, cox2, cox_lasso, cox_net, rsf),
                     tasks       = task,
                     resamplings = outer_cv,
                     keep.extract= TRUE, 
                     models      = TRUE,
                     show.info   = TRUE)

end_time <- Sys.time()
end_time - start_time
parallelStop()

getBMRFeatSelResults(bmr)
getBMRFilteredFeatures(bmr)
getBMRTuneResults(bmr)
```

Comment: benchmark is there to unbiasedly evaluate the performance of a learner (nested resampling or holdout test data). This is just to get an idea what level of performance you can expect (also variance of the performance) and how much the optimal hyper parameters vary depending on the data splits. In order to tune a learner for future use, tune the hyper parameters using resampling on all of the data you have, and then train it on all of the data you have using the optimal hyper parameters.

Comment: An excerpt from the mlr3 book: "Keep in mind that nested resampling is a statistical procedure to estimate the predictive performance of the model trained on the full dataset. Nested resampling is not a procedure to select optimal hyperparameters. "

Comment: Thanks for your response. I do know resampling is to assess the model performance for unseen data (generalization of results) and hyperparameters optimization is to find the best parameter set  for a given the data. Nested resampling is when we combine both resampling and tuning which I am doing. I want to get the inner tuning results from benchmark (https://mlr3gallery.mlr-org.com/posts/2020-03-11-mlr3tuning-tutorial-german-credit/). What benchmark dose is really run resample for every task and leaner combination. So what is the difference between running resample directly vs via benchmark.

Comment: Help me understand 
Given the results from the benchmark, should I only tune the highest performing model using the entire train data set, then train and predict on test set. Or should tune all models regardless of the benchmark results (pointless)? 
Or, should I first tune all models using all train set then compare models using benchmark with tuning (nested resampling) using narrow search space based on the tuning results (I don't think I should fix hyperparameters to optimal set)? How different the tuning results will be from resample using all training data vs from benchmark?

Comment: There is an open question about the ‘best’ way to do what you want but in my experience I have done and seen the following:

1. Split your data into training and testing
2. Run a nested benchmark experiment on the training data
3. Train and tune the best-performing learner on the complete training data
4. Make predictions on the test data

Comment: Thanks very much Raphael

Comment: You might also want to read [Tune a Support Vector Machine](https://mlr3gallery.mlr-org.com/posts/2021-03-09-practical-tuning-series-tune-a-support-vector-machine). The post explains what you can do with nested resampling results and how to get a final model.

Comment: @be-marc thanks for sharing